# Parsing file with parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am trying to parse file [1] but below code is not working properly.

```
import Control.Applicative hiding ( many , ( <|> )  )
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser) 
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as T
import Text.Parsec.Language (emptyDef)

--Scheme Code;ISIN Div Payout/ ISIN Growth;ISIN Div Reinvestment;Scheme Name;Net Asset Value;Repurchase Price;Sale Price;Date
--120523;INF846K01ET8;INF846K01EU6;Axis Triple Advantage Fund - Direct Plan - Dividend Option;13.3660;13.2323;13.3660;19-Jun-2015

data MFund = MFund Integer  String String String Double Double Double String deriving (Show) --String String String  deriving (Show)

lexer :: T.TokenParser st
lexer  = T.makeTokenParser emptyDef

natural :: Parser Integer
natural = T.natural lexer

float :: Parser Double
float = T.float lexer

eol :: Parser String
eol =  try (string "\r\n")
   <|> try (string "\n")
   <|> try (string "\r")

parseFund :: Parsec String () MFund
parseFund = MFund <$> natural 
              <*> (char ';' *> (many1 alphaNum <|> string "-")) 
              <*> (char ';' *> (many1 alphaNum <|> string "-")) 
              <*> (char ';' *> manyTill anyChar (char ';'))
              <*> float
              <*> (char ';' *> float)
              <*> (char ';' *> float)
              <*> (char ';' *> many1 (alphaNum <|> char '-'))



parseBlockFund :: Parsec String () [MFund]
parseBlockFund = manyTill anyChar eol *> space *> eol *> endBy parseFund eol

parseMutual :: Parsec String () [MFund]
parseMutual = concat <$> (manyTill anyChar eol *> space *> eol *>
          sepBy parseBlockFund (space *> eol))

{- each scheme is seperated by space and end of line-}
parseSchemeBlock :: Parsec String () [MFund]
parseSchemeBlock = concat <$> (sepBy parseMutual (space *> eol))

parseFile :: Parsec String () [MFund]
parseFile = 
   string "Scheme Code;ISIN Div Payout/ ISIN Growth;ISIN Div Reinvestment;Scheme Name;Net Asset Value;Repurchase Price;Sale Price;Date" *>
   eol *> space *> eol *> parseSchemeBlock <* eof


main :: IO ()
main = do 
 input <- readFile "data.txt"
 print input
 case parse  parseFile  "" input  of
    Left err -> print err
    Right val -> print val
```

I am starting to parse the file from parseFile function which consumes first line, end of line, space and end of line. Now I parse each scheme blocks which are separated by space and end of line. Within each scheme block, we have many mutual blocks which are also separated by space and end of line so I first consume the string till end of line followed by space and end of line and call parseBlockFund.

The problem which I suspect is when I am calling parseMutual function and when it's reaching to end of scheme block, it eats the space and end of line which is suppose to be consumed by parseSchemeBlock function. I tried try function but it's not working so I am not sure if I am thinking correctly or not. Could some one please tell me what is wrong with this code.

One interesting thing when I remove the eof, this code is able to parse at least one scheme block [2].

[1] http://portal.amfiindia.com/spages/NAV0.txt

[2] https://github.com/mukeshtiwari/Puzzles/blob/master/Assigment/Api.hs

Comment: It's hard to keep track of where whitespace was supposed to be consumed, because the code is scattered with `space` and `eol` in many places. With a simple line-based format like this, you really want to deal with whole lines at a time. I would try writing a `line :: Parser a -> Parser a` combinator, which parses an `a` then eagerly chomps the space and newlines afterwards. (But be cautious that `a` itself doesn't consume newlines.)